# accessing property from external configuration using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

I have a spring boot web service in which I'm trying to access an external property in a controller, e.g.

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @Value( "${my.name}" )
    String myname
...
```

The problem is that it fails to compile, giving the error

```
Attribute 'value' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
```

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

--john

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you're using Groovy. If so, the use of `$` causes the String to become a GString. You'll need to either escape it with a backslash:

```
@Value("\${my.name}")
```

Or use single quotes:

```
@Value('${my.name}')
```

Comment: Thanks Andy.  That was indeed the problem and I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't see it myself.

I appreciate the help!